# Read Build number from .xcconfig file like Version number in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, environment-variables

i created this `Release.xcconfig`:

```
SB_APP_NAME = Test
SB_APP_VERSION = 0.5
SB_APP_BUILD = 5
SB_APP_BUNDLE_ID = com.test.ios
```

and now i can use `SB_APP_VERSION` in `info.plist` like this:

[image]

but i can't find any key for `build number` in `plist` file to replace it from my `xcconfig` file.

as you can see, we have `Version` and `Build` in `General` tab of project. i want to read this number from `xcconfig`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we see in `info.plist` file, we can find `Bundle version string (short)` and `Bundle version`. so:

`Bundle version string (short)` => `App Version` ( in general tab ) ( like 5.3.1 )

`Bundle version` => `App Build` ( in general tab ) ( like any int number )

---

So we can replace `Bundle Version` value as `$(SB_APP_BUILD)`

Comment: after changing this, i cannot see App Version and App Build in General Tab